# cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<x>' to 'x' when using automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, automapper

I have `NewsViewModel`, which includes :

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public CategoryViewModel()
    {
        List = new List<CategoryModel>();
    }
    public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> List { get; set; }
    public CategoryModel CategoryModel { get; set; }
}
```

`ListNews`  to show list of news; and

`NewsModel`  for edit or insert.

Now I need to use `automapper`. The code below gives me an error:

```
public PartialViewResult Edit(int id)
{
    var model = new CategoryViewModel();
    var cat = _CategoryService.CategoryByID(id);
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryModel>());
    model.CategoryModel = Mapper.Map<Category, CategoryModel>(cat);
    var categorymodel = _CategoryService.GetAllCategory();
    Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Category, IEnumerable<CategoryModel>>());
    model.List = Mapper.Map<Category, IEnumerable<CategoryModel>>(categorymodel);
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Firstly, you're misusing automapper, you shouldn't be calling `Mapper.Initialize` in you methods. The configuration should all be done in either the `Startup.cs` or the `Global.asax`

Comment: Show CategoryViewModel.

Comment: How did you install Automapper in the first place?
Install-Package AutoMaper ?
Did it work?

Comment: @CallumLinington i not missing `automaper` and i using `Mapper.Initialize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create new map for collections if you have map for types of those collections. So remove this line:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Category, IEnumerable<CategoryModel>>());
```

Also you are trying to map single object to collection. You should map collection to collections instead:

```
// move next line to Application_Start
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Category, CategoryModel>());     

var model = new CategoryViewModel();
var category = _CategoryService.CategoryByID(id);
model.CategoryModel = Mapper.Map<CategoryModel>(category);
var categories = _CategoryService.GetAllCategory();
model.List = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CategoryModel>>(categories);
```

Further considerations:

- Use `Mapper.Map<TDestination>` instead of `Mapper.Map<TSource,TDestination>` because type of source can be inferred from method argument
- Use meaningful names of variables. There is no need to save few characters to use `cat` instead of `category`. And name `categoryModel` is just misleading - this variable holds list of categories.
- And last - don't create maps each time you want to map objects. Create maps once on application start.